# Programming BeagleBone Green Wireless without installing an image?

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have just had an [SeeedStudio BeagleBone Green Wireless](http://wiki.seeed.cc/SeeedStudio_BeagleBone_Green_Wireless/). It's completely compatible with BeagleBone Black and I know that it has already had an Linux in on-board 4GB eMMC.

So I think I could program the GPIO of the board without installing a new image (in Micro SD Card). But when I tried to write value 1 to GPIO 48, I didn't see the LED flash.

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio# echo 48 > export
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio44# echo out > direction
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/gpio/gpio44# echo 1 > value
```

I tried it with Cloud9 IDE in an different language also but it's still not successful. When I change the connection of the bus from GPIO 48 to the VCC, the LED was bright, so the hardware setup was ok.

Is there any reason behind the scences ?

Do I need to install an image in SD Card to program the GPIO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You export 48 then use gpio44 (based on prompt).